# How to stream into c# form data received from serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port, serial-communication

I want to print into c# form (into Richtextbox maybe) the data being given by my arduino. I am able to connect tjhe serial port, but my current code is giving just the last printed value. I want to print it in the vertical stream the way it is shown in Serial Monitor of arduino software. How to do it?

My code presently:

```
private void settext(string val)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = val;
    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string incomstring = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        settext(incomstring);
    }
```

The image (check the serial monitor) of what I am trying to achieve in my C# form:

[Serial Monitor in Arduino IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3VNq.png)

Comment: Please add some code and maybe an example of what you want to achieve. We cannot guess how you are reading values currently, so that would be interesting to see.

Comment: @Fildor I have made changes to my question.

Comment: Use RichTextBox.AppendText() instead.  And you must use the form's BeginInvoke() method so that method runs on the UI thread, never set the CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls property to false to stop the framework from telling you there's a bug in your code.